# Downloaded Magento Website from a server, but having difficulties running it on a local server.

Tags: php, magento, hosting, mamp

I am not a magento developer and I know basic PHP (not the best start I know), but I said I would help a friend out with some front end changes.

However, I downloaded a magento website from a server and attempted to host it on a local server using MAMP but I receive the following error:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/408p2kgfyhkebwy/Screenshot%202018-09-22%2014.12.09.png?dl=0

This is what my directory looks like:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/a7je3odeg9ia1gi/Screenshot%202018-09-22%2014.13.44.png?dl=0

So what do you think I should do? I will debug it myself but any help would be welcome.

Thank you,

Raman

Comment: Have you check magento log files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Go to index.php file and enable developer mode to display errors and warnings on page .Please make sure that you have exported database from live server and imported on localhost also change the Database credentials in app/etc/local.xml and disable the compilation from admin if enabled before backing-up.
If issue is still there please have a look over log files too.